# How to model a complex json file as a python class

Tags: python, json

Are there any python helper libraries I can use to create models that I can use to generate complex json files, such as this. I've read about colander but I'm not sure it does what I need. The tricky bit about the following is that the `trigger-rule` section may have nested `match` rules, something as described at https://github.com/adnanh/webhook/wiki/Hook-Rules

```
[
  {
    "id": "webhook",
    "execute-command": "/home/adnan/redeploy-go-webhook.sh",
    "command-working-directory": "/home/adnan/go",
    "pass-arguments-to-command":
    [
      {
        "source": "payload",
        "name": "head_commit.id"
      },
      {
        "source": "payload",
        "name": "pusher.name"
      },
      {
        "source": "payload",
        "name": "pusher.email"
      }
    ],
    "trigger-rule":
    {
      "and":
      [
        {
          "match":
          {
            "type": "payload-hash-sha1",
            "secret": "mysecret",
            "parameter":
            {
              "source": "header",
              "name": "X-Hub-Signature"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match":
          {
            "type": "value",
            "value": "refs/heads/master",
            "parameter":
            {
              "source": "payload",
              "name": "ref"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a class like this:

```
class AttributeDictionary(dict):
    __getattr__ = dict.__getitem__
    __setattr__ = dict.__setitem__
```

When you load your JSON, pass `AttributeDictionary` as the `object_hook`:

```
import json

data = json.loads(json_str, object_hook=AttributeDictionary)
```

Then you can access `dict` entries by specifying the key as an attribute:

```
print data[0].id
```

**Output**

```
webhook
```

**Note:** You will want to replace dashes in keys with underscores. If you don't, this approach won't work on those keys.

Comment: Thanks for the novel approach, I have to use dashes in keys though, I'm generating the config for webhooks.go, I'm marking this as the answer

Comment: You can always access the keys without dashes as attributes and use strings to access the rest of the keys.